# Is there a way to construct tuple with extra properties without cast to any?

Tags: typescript

In order to support both array and object destructuring, I have the following `Result` type definition:

```
type Errors = Record<string, string | null>

type Result = [Errors, boolean] & { errors: Errors, success: boolean }
```

I have tried to construct such result in one statement, but could not find syntax that could do such a thing...
Also, this other approach fails with error:

```
const result: Result = [errors, success]
result.errors = errors
result.success = success
return result
```

> Type '[Errors, boolean]' is not assignable to type 'Result'.
>
> Type '[Errors, boolean]' is not assignable to type '{ errors:
> Errors; success: boolean; }'

However, declaring result as `any` and applying type on the return works:

```
const result: any = [errors, success]
result.errors = errors
result.success = success
return result as Result
```

**Is there better, type safe way to construct such object?**

Comment: Even with a type safe way to construct such an object, there is no way to guarantee that `result[0]` is the same as `result.errors` (and same for `success`). This would make a very confusing API. I would suggest you choose one of the two ways and stick with it.

Comment: You could use `Object.assign` to construct `Result` as demonstrated here: https://tsplay.dev/mMBElW. However, this still requires an assertion for the tuple.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I agree, can be confusing... I just was influenced by `i18n` hook https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook which supports both ways of destructuring... Anyway, I will probably switch to object approach then.

Also discussed here, take a look at the comments: https://betterprogramming.pub/this-pattern-will-make-your-react-hooks-cleaner-ca9deba5d58d

Comment: @TobiasS. That looks much better than `any`. You can write answer in case anyone still needs and wants to go this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this where you want an object to be both `A` and `B` at the same time but can't do an assignment in one line can often be solved with `Object.assign()`. This function allows combining two JavaScript objects at runtime and is also conveniently typed to intersect both object types.

The only problem in this case is the way that TypeScript types array literals. We need an assertion to tell TypeScript to type the passed array as a tuple.

```
const result: Result = Object.assign(
    { errors, success }, 
    [errors, success] as [Errors, boolean]
)
```

This reduces the type-safety as the type assertion allows us to forget an element in the tuple or to add some other element.

You *could* type `Result` to be an `readonly` array.

```
type Result = readonly [Errors, boolean] & { errors: Errors, success: boolean }
```

Then we could use `as const`.

```
const result: Result = Object.assign(
    { errors, success }, 
    [errors, success] as const
)
```

Which would give us 100% type-safety.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAzlAvFAShAxsgEwB4Vg4BLAOwHMAaKUimqAHykoFcAbLgPgFgAUENCRsEFN2AYocCAEMCiSlxBQA2vCSp6AI0SIuCygF0oAMigBvKBATIUALlj2dDDrlwSnUfYeNQAL5CQviUpLauaJhWQlDxUPLOAEQAjABMAMzJQsGCYRGSnt4yAGbyXCgQIfnKEXKSXMDOOI3SmADyugBWeMAAdPIoKOTUlAAUcQk2dtoo9EVew0H0U-Hqsw4LHksoZkNQBcBCAJRAA)